# How to explain a change in research interests for an application for a doctoral position?

Tags: phd, physics, germany, research-statement

At the moment I'm writing a statement of research interest for a doctoral position in physics, more precisely theoretical quantum technology. The problem I have is that my master's thesis was mostly about numerical astrophysics. The work of the group I'm applying for is pretty mathematics-oriented with only some parts of numerical work and the two topics of astrophysics and quantum technology are quite different. Now I don't know how to discuss this shift of interest in a good manner. During my master studies I mostly chose lectures with a high amount of mathematics (General relativity, quantum information technology, nonlinear dynamics etc.), but my master thesis only had a small analytic part. Thanks in advance for some general advises and tips on how to build a bridge between these topics!

Comment: Is this for doctoral study in US, or elsewhere?

Comment: I dunno, why did you change interests?

Comment: It's for a doctoral study in germany